# Keycloak http://localhost:8080/auth unable to acess

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper, keycloak-connect

I am trying to implement keycloak in Angular. So I have downloaded the 'keycloak-12.0.2.[zip|tar.gz]' file. I have ran the command **C:\Users\XXXX\XXXXX\keycloak-12.0.2\bin> standalone.bat** in cmd.
But when I try to access the keycloak admin login console. It is showing to **localhost refused to connect**

Tried the below command as well **standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0**

I am using windows 8.1 and my IP address is 192.168.xx.xx

[Please see the attached screen shot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCYjB.png)

Comment: In the logs of Keycloak do you see any port related warnings ?

Comment: Thanks @dreamcrash for pointing it out... Yes I was getting an exception. I had this problem when I extracted the keycloak tar.gz download file. But when I used the zip file and this error went away

Comment: So it is solved now? :)